# How to set predefined values for dataGridView in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a dataGridView with two columns, (URL and RedirectTo)

[image: dataGridView1]

I want to set predefined values, so when the Windows Form show-up, user will see some predefined values

[image]

How to set predefined value for a dataGridView component ?

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as you aren't bound to a data source :

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("http://microsoft.com", "http://facebook.com");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("http://yahoo.com", "stackoverflow.com");
```

You can put it in your form's `OnLoad` event

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView.Rows.Add(predefinedValue1, predefinedValue2, ...);
```

Edit: Bah, beaten to the punch.